# Xcode crashes when trying to submit an app to the app store

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to submit an app. I archived it and then tried to submit it and upon so, it crashes. I looked up potential fixes to this problem and they said just go to preferences > accounts > and update to make sure you've agreed to all new terms. So I did that and tried it again and now it's still crashing. I haven't found any other solutions.

Edit: I went through the itunes connect instead and I think that should work, but I'm still curious as to why there's an error.

Comment: Strange. I got the same error today, on one of my two apps I have to submit.

Comment: Just close your Xcode and keep opened the organizer when you submit. It should work (its worked for me)

Answer (score 19):

Today Xcode started crashing during 'Submit to App Store' in the Organizer. It had worked just fine every time before today. 
Here are the steps I used to upload the app build to iTunes Connect:

1. In Organizer, Export and create the ipa using 'Save for iOS App Store Deployment'
2. Open Application Loader in Xcode->Open Developer Tools->Application Loader
3. Login in to Application Loader and  Choose the 'Deliver Your App' to upload the ipa file
4. Open iTunes Connect to check the build upload and to select the build

Answer (score 2):

unfortunatley i can't add comments so i'm posting my answer to suggest. if you are facing issue wih xCode you can upload your application by using "Application Loader".If You face still errors kindly share your's error text.