# Xcode crashes when putting submitting my app to the App Store Why?

Tags: xcode, crash, app-store

I archived it then I validated it and when I submit the app xcode crashes. Has anyone had this problem and do they know how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Mine crashes when it's about to upload not when fetching team list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899017/xcode-crashes-when-trying-to-submit-an-app-to-the-app-store